# Problem of rewriting a t-test in python in R

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I want to rewrite a python code (actually Jupyter Book) in R. It is about computing a t-test function for some data to visualise it after that  using boxplot.

I am beginner in Python and R but I made some tries. This is the code in python:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from myst_nb import glue
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

labels = ['non-failing heart (NF)', 'failing heart (F)']
data = [(99, 52), (96, 40), (100, 38), (105, 18), 
        (np.nan, 11), (np.nan, 5), (np.nan, 42), 
        (np.nan, 55), (np.nan, 53), (np.nan, 39),
        (np.nan, 42), (np.nan, 50)]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=labels)
tt = ttest_ind(df['non-failing heart (NF)'], 
               df['failing heart (F)'], 
               equal_var=False, nan_policy='omit')

pvalue = tt.pvalue

glue('pvalue', math.ceil(pvalue * 1000.0) / 1000.0)
```

This is what I've tried:

```
library(math)

labels(data) <- c("non-failing heart (NF)", "failing heart (F)")
library(reticulate)
np <- import("numpy", convert=FALSE)
(x <- np$arange(1, 9)$reshape(2L, 2L))
## [[  99.   52.]
##   [  96.   40.]
##   [  100.   38.]
##   [  105.   18.]
##   [ np.nan.   11.]
##   [ np.nan.  5.]
##   [ np.nan.  42.]
##   [ np.nan.  55.]
##   [ np.nan  53.]
##   [ np.nan  39.]
##   [ np.nan.  42.]
##   [ np.nan  50.]
##   [ 23.  24.]]


df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=labels)
tt = ttest_ind(df['non-failing heart (NF)'], 
               df['failing heart (F)'], 
               equal_var=False, nan_policy='omit')

pvalue = tt.pvalue
print(pvalue)
```

Comment: Hello, you have a little way to go. personally if i was writing in R, I wouldn't use reticulate. For your information, this is the built in R t.test function https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/t.test

Comment: @M.Viking Thank you for trying to help me, ok I will follow the example writtin in the link, just a question, for the data how to rewrite the np.nan values ? they are from the python numpy which R cannot provides it

Comment: R has the `NA` entity.

Comment: @Parfait Thanks for replying me, can you please explain more ? Did you mean that I can use NA instead of numpy, if yes, how?

Comment: The best translation of Python's `numpy.nan` is `NA` in R. In fact, R has NAs for [all types](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/NA.html): `NA_integer_`, `NA_real_`, `NA_complex_`, and `NA_character_`. `NA` denotes `NA_logical_`. Since `np.nan` is a float type, `NA_real_` may be the best version but R will convert by the higher type order: logical > integer > numeric > character > factor > complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, [`t.test`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/t.test) is among the many built-in statistical methods in R in its `stats` library. Therefore, simply build the same data frame, then run the test and extract test statistics as needed.

**Data Build** *(some wrangling to replicate `pd.DataFrame.from_records()`)*

```r
labels <- list('non-failing heart (NF)', 'failing heart (F)')

data <- list(c(99, 52), c(96, 40), c(100, 38), c(105, 18), 
             c(NA_integer_, 11), c(NA_integer_, 5), c(NA_integer_, 42), 
             c(NA_integer_, 55), c(NA_integer_, 53), c(NA_integer_, 39),
             c(NA_integer_, 42), c(NA_integer_, 50))

df <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, 
                       lapply(data, function(d) data.frame(d[1], d[2]))),
              labels)    
df
#    non-failing heart (NF) failing heart (F)
# 1                      99                52
# 2                      96                40
# 3                     100                38
# 4                     105                18
# 5                      NA                11
# 6                      NA                 5
# 7                      NA                42
# 8                      NA                55
# 9                      NA                53
# 10                     NA                39
# 11                     NA                42
# 12                     NA                50
```

**T-test**

```r
results <- t.test(df[['non-failing heart (NF)']], df[['failing heart (F)']])

results
#   Welch Two Sample t-test

# data:  df[["non-failing heart (NF)"]] and df[["failing heart (F)"]]
# t = 12.114, df = 13.43, p-value = 1.311e-08
# alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  51.73232 74.10101
# sample estimates:
# mean of x mean of y 
# 100.00000  37.08333 
    
results$statistic
#        t 
# 12.11356 

results$estimate
# mean of x mean of y 
# 100.00000  37.08333 

results$p.value
# [1] 1.311125e-08

ceiling(results$p.value * 1000.0)/ 1000.0
# [1] 0.001
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me and the good work that you did. 
I tried to run your code with RStudio and I am getting that the x is null.
This is the hole error: `Fehler in var(x) : 'x' ist NULL
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldung:
In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

Comment: Likely it is your actual data which appears to be an attempt to run on a non-number column. Posted code here and your sample data works without error. See online demo: https://rextester.com/IHS73217.